# Creating a self signed certificate for demonstration purposes on Centos 7 server

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have setup my default tomcat website (tomcat 8.0.3) on a server inside my company LAN. From my work computer if I try to access the website by typing it into google chrome it is not working.

The IP of the computer on which the Tomcat server is running is `192.1xx.132.125:8080`. The IP of my work computer is `192.1xx.129.75`.

It is currently accessed as `http://192.1xx.132.125:8080`. I want to make it an https site for demonstration purposes. How do I create a certificate at the server and make my google chrome browser treat that certificate as a trusted certificate.

Comment: See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure, almost positive that self-signed certificates aren't counted as trusted. It's pretty much the same thing as you signing your own doctorate. It won't be trusted by your colleagues, as it was created by the person it's for.

However, self-signed certificates are good for things like mail-servers.

**Edit:** If you'd like a regular certificate, [NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates.aspx) offers SSL certs at a pretty good price.

Comment: I get the idea.I am aksing for some means by configuring my browser to treat it as trusted for a specific purpose.

Comment: @BillThor's answer works, too :P

Answer (score 1):

You can import the certificate into Chrome to make it trusted.

The process I use is to:

- Create a CA using openssl. (I use tinyCA as as GUI.)
- Create a certificate signed by the CA for my site.
- Import my CA certificate into clients (browers, email readers, etc.).
- Install the certificate in the server I wish to use.

Comment: Who is the CA in this case? Am I myself the CA.? How do I install the certificate in my Tomcat8.0.3 server?

Comment: @liv2hak  Yes, you will be your own CA.   Tomcat should use the Java keystore.  Follow their documentation for generating a certificate and getting it signed.  Sign it with your CA certificate, then import the signed certificate.